# can I change the NFA algorithm by removing the repeated stage to prevent Regex DOS

Tags: regex, algorithm

As my knowledge to Regex algorithm , it transfers Regex to NFA.
By the definition of Regex, it would try all possibilities so it would record all possible stages to an array.
But for the bad Regex, it would save too many stages inside array then the algorithm would blow out.
The bad Regex like /(a+)+/
My question is : Can i simply remove the repeated stage in the array then it would not blow out the memory to prevent all the Regex DOS?
Would this reduce the abilities of Regex ?

Comment: You seem to be talking about regexps and some specific implementation of regexp matching interchangeably, but there's more than one implementation. Good implementations match in time linear to the length of the regexp and don't suffer from DOS attacks. https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Comment: Thanks for comment! But why programming language (etc. Javascript) choose the one suffered from DOS attacks?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know the reasons behind the design decisions of Javascript.

Comment: In the article shows that Ruby/Python/JS/Perl all implement the bad one. I am so curious about why the kernel teams choose the vulnerable algorithm.
It must be something considerable that I miss.
Thanks for the useful info again. :)

Comment: Features like capture groups, lookahead, and backreferences are not supported by NFA or DFA-based implementations